# How can I change the Stack Size available for Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

When I run *anything-c-etags-select* command with relatively big TAGS file, I always get the error message like *Stack overflow in regexp matcher* inside the mini buffer on Emacs.  In `*Messages*` buffer, there appears the log message as follows:

```
File TAGS is large (9MB), really open? (y or n) 
Loading tag file...70%
and: Stack overflow in regexp matcher
```

It seems that Emacs doesn't have enough stack size to read whole tag data.  Is there any way to increase stack size for Emacs?

I tried this with 2 versions of Emacs:

- Emacs For Mac OS X 24.1 (Universal Binary)
- Emacs For Mac OS X 23.4 (Universal Binary)

But, both of them showed the same error message.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to see whether replacing `Anything` with [`Helm`](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm#readme) resolves the issue, as the latter is being actively developed.

Comment: Thank you!  I tried `Helm`, but there still exists the same problem.

Comment: You could submit a bug report to them, in that case; perhaps they can fix it for the next release.

Comment: Just to point out the obvious, this seems like a bug in the regex; the stack should be large enough for any sane use, and increasing it probably doesn't help in most scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly easy workarounds for you:

> - http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultilineRegexp
>
> Better yet: [\0-\377[:nonascii:]]* avoids “Stack overflow in regexp
>   matcher” for huge texts, e.g., > 34k.

... and/or ...

> - http://www.svi.nl/EmacsProgrammingTips
>
> My tags tables are in different places, depending on the code I'm
>   working with. I found it easy to have an environmental variable
>   $DEVELOP pointing to the directory I'm working in, which has TAGS for
>   Emacs and tags for vi.

Comment: Thank you!  These 2 links are helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed that if 2nd argument for *string-match* function is too big, the function fails to handle the argument.  I added a restriction for the function as follows:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/lisp/anything/anything-config.el b/lisp/anything/anything-config.el
index 23f00e5..cee5e13 100644
--- a/lisp/anything/anything-config.el
+++ b/lisp/anything/anything-config.el
@@ -7001,7 +7001,7 @@ If not found in CURRENT-DIR search in upper directory."
                        (anything-aif (string-match "\177" i)
                            (substring i 0 it)
                          i))
-           do (cond ((and elm (string-match "^\\(.+\\),[0-9]+" elm))
+           do (cond ((and elm (< (length elm) 2000) (string-match "^\\(.+\\),[0-9]+" elm))
                      (setq fname (match-string 1 elm)))
                     (elm (setq cand (concat fname ": " elm)))
                     (t (setq cand nil)))
```

I think It's a kind of quick and dirty hack, but it's working fine now.

Comment: I've added an [issue](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/77) for helm.  Please switch to it and submit PR.